# How to use cd to locate a file and then open the file in vim easily in least possible keystrokes?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

Very often I find myself in a situation where I would `cd` into a really deep directory structure to traverse to a file and then would have to open the file in vim.. So while doing cd I constantly keep pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key after entering only a part of the filename to autocomplete the name  and ultimately reach the file I am interested in. Then I will have to go to the beginning of the command line using <kbd>CTRL+A</kbd> and then deleting the `cd` and inserting `vi`. Is there a faster way of doing what I want to achieve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash also autocompletes paths for you if you use `vi` instead of `cd`, so just do:

```
vi /some/folder/TabTab…/foo/TabTab…
```

You might also be interested in [`autojump`](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump), which helps you access directories quicker. [`fasd`](https://github.com/clvv/fasd) is similar and gives you quick access to files, too.